Efficiently managing CSS in a monorepo with Next.js, iframe components, and HMR support
I'm working on a monorepo project with the following structure:

A Next.js web app
A UI package (no build process, transpiled in Next.js)
A builder package (currently using tsup)

My challenge is with the builder package, which uses components from the UI package and needs to render them in an iframe(react-frame-component). The UI package uses Tailwind CSS, which is built separately.
Current setup:

UI package: Tailwind CSS built to ./dist/index.css
Builder package: using tsup --watch in dev mode and tsup in build mode
Web app: Imports and uses both UI and builder packages

Issues:

Can't directly import CSS in the iframe within the builder package
No public path in the builder to use in link element
Need HMR support for development

I've considered:

Dynamic CSS loading (doesn't work due to no public path and HMR issues)
Inline CSS generation (this would be possible if use vite or some build tool, like raw-loader)
CSS-in-JS solutions (cannot use because we are using tailwind already.
Setting up a build system for the builder package, but the problem is in dev mode, cause I think in build --watch mode not same as dev for vite or rsbuild. maybe there are others solution for this

What's the most efficient way to:

Use UI package styles in the builder's iframe components
Maintain HMR support in development
Keep the build process simple and efficient

Also do i need to introduce micro frontend or module federation etc?
this is my ui package.json:
{
  "name": "@ezy/ui",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "main": "./src/index.ts",
  "types": "./src/index.ts",
  "sideEffects": [
    "**/*.css"
  ],
  "exports": {
    ".": "./src/index.ts",
    "./icons": "./src/icons/index.tsx",
    "./styles.css": "./dist/index.css"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint . --max-warnings 0",
    "build": "tailwindcss -i ./src/styles/main.css -o ./dist/index.css --minify",
    "dev": "tailwindcss -i ./src/styles/main.css -o ./dist/index.css --watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ezy/config": "workspace:*",
    "@ezy/eslint-config": "workspace:*",
    "@types/eslint": "8.56.6",
    "@types/node": "22.5.5",
    "@types/react": "18.3.7",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.3.0",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.20",
    "class-variance-authority": "0.7.0",
    "eslint": "8.57.0",
    "postcss": "8.4.47",
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "tailwindcss": "3.4.12",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "1.0.7",
    "typescript": "5.6.2"
  },
  ...otherConfig
}

builder package.json
{
  "name": "@ezy/builder",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "tsup --watch",
    "build": "tsup"
  },
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/index.js"
    },
    "./index.css": "./dist/index.css"
  },
  "files": [
    "*.ts"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@ezy/shared": "workspace:*",
    "@ezy/test-data": "workspace:*",
    "@ezy/ui": "workspace:*",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "0.2.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "2.2.3",
    "array-to-condition": "1.1.2",
    "react-dnd": "16.0.1",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "16.0.1",
    "react-draggable": "4.4.6",
    "react-frame-component": "5.2.7",
    "react-icons": "5.3.0",
    "react-redux": "9.1.2",
    "stylis": "4.3.4",
    "xss": "1.0.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ezy/config": "workspace:*",
    "@ezy/eslint-config": "workspace:*",
    "@types/eslint": "8.56.5",
    "@types/node": "20.11.20",
    "@types/react": "18.3.7",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.3.0",
    "@types/stylis": "4.2.5",
    "eslint": "8.57.0",
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "tsup": "8.3.0",
    "typescript": "5.6.2"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "next": "^14.2",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "tsup": {
    "entry": [
      "./src/index.ts"
    ],
    "splitting": false,
    "sourcemap": true,
    "dts": true
  }
}

in react-frame-component I need to pass css like this
<Frame
   id={id}
   className="builder min-h-[calc(100vh-56px)] w-full"
   head={
          <>
            <style dangerouslySetInnerHTML={styles} />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/builder.css" />
            {globalStyles && <style>{globalStyles}</style>}
          </>
   }
   title={title}
   {...rest}>
     <DndFrame>{children}</DndFrame>
</Frame>

but the problem is i cannot find any public path for ui css or any raw loader to get text content for the styles. and need support for hmr in iframe too.
I'm open to restructuring the build process or using different tools if necessary. What's the best approach for this scenario that aligns with industry standards for production-grade applications?
